# VBA Inputbox criteria is set incorrectly-Need to end macro

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I am an idiot and set an input box to endlessly loop

```
    InputBoxx:
    Again = InputBox("Question?" & vbLf & "1) Answer 1" & vbLf& vbLf & "2) Answer 2" & vbLf & "3) Answer 3" & vbLf & vbLf & "Please Enter the number that corresponds to your selection")

If Again <> 1 Or Again <> 2 Or Again <> 3 Then MsgBox "Hey now, that wasn't one of the choices....", vbCritical: GoTo InputBoxx:
```

Is there a way to end the loop without closing Excel? I have pressed Escape, Cancel, etc.

Comment: It would be much better to use a Userform that restricts what the user can select instead of relying on a loop like that.

Comment: Also consider using `vbNewLine` instead of concatenating `vbLf` characters. FYI on Windows, line breaks are `vbCr+vbLf`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have to hit Ctrl+Break to interrupt the run.